# Swift 2.0 - is the programming logic different from languages?

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I am new to Swift 2.0 programming. I made an app integrate with Parse. Following is the snippet of my code

```
 private func isIdNotFound() ->Bool{

    var notFound = true

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Customer")
    query.whereKey("customerId", equalTo: self.id)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil &&  objects != nil{
            print(objects)
            notFound = false
            print(notFound)
        }
    }
    print(notFound)
    return notFound
}
```

The console:

```
true
<Customer: 0x7feccbf07ef0, objectId: AiPH5pNgum, localId: (null)> {
    customerId = wilson93;
    email = 123;
    password = 123;
    }])
false
```

Why is it that it prints `true` then only it runs the logic and print `false`. As far as other languages such Java, it should print false twice.

Comment: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` Note the "in background" part. You have asynchronous execution here. The method returns before the query is completed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, your code is `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`. Here, `Background` is the keyword. Because you are searching asynchronously, therefore not necessarily in the order the code is written, the *second* instance of `print(notFound)` is executed *before* the instance in the block.

You can tell because, if read out loud, the two `print` statements are right next to each other (excluding braces) but `notFound` is not printed twice in succession. `objects` is printed after the first (second instance in code) print statement but *before* the other one.

```
var notFound = true

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil &&  objects != nil{
        print(objects) //this comes second
        notFound = false
        print(notFound) //then this comes last
    }
}
print(notFound) //this runs first
```

See the [documentation for `PFQuery` here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:). It says, *in italics*, that the search is performed asynchronously.

From the doc:

> Finds objects *asynchronously* and calls the given block with the results.

```
- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFQueryArrayResultBlock)block
```

Parameters

IIRC, this means that the search is run on another thread.
@Community correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I read the documentation and found out that i should be using getFirstObject() or findObjects(). But the code in the documentation shows error in my Xcode. `let query = PFQuery(className: "Customer")
        query.whereKey("customerId", equalTo: self.id)
        
        let object = query.getFirstObject()`

Comment: Are you sure your framework/library/whatever you use for Parse is up to date? What error do you get?

Comment: i just downloaded the parse documents it today...so should be the latest right?

Comment: is there any guidance you can show? Im really stuck here.. my code `let query = PFQuery(className: "Customer")
        query.whereKey("customerId", equalTo: self.id)
       let getId =  query.getFirstObject()
        if getId != nil{
            notFound = false
        }`

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to use `getFirstObject`?